# REST Api result with filed description

Tags: jquery, python, json, api, jira

I need to do a search on JIRA, but my search result does not contain *Description*, I added fields=description at the end, but it does not work:

http://myapp.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project%3DPROJECT&fields=description

Answer (score 0):

`&fields=description` means that what ever is returned in fields, it is filtered to only return description property

so -
use `&expand=fields` - to get more data on the fields Jason object, which includes description and use `&fields=description` to filter the newly expanded fields object, to get only description and not the full one